# Draw background with white dots with CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes

I know it's possible to draw [this](http://images.clipartpanda.com/polka-clipart-pattern_dots_red_white.png) background using only CSS (so without making use of image files). I'm curious on how I can do this. I've found a lot of information about making gradients and such with CSS3 on the web, but I've never found any guide that explains how to create something more advanced than this image as background in CSS. Any ideas on how to get started?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not my fiddle, but I found this: http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/RtGsM/

```
body {
    background:
        -moz-radial-gradient(white 15%, transparent 16%),
        -moz-radial-gradient(white 15%, transparent 16%),
        black;
    background:
    -webkit-radial-gradient(white 15%, transparent 16%),
    -webkit-radial-gradient(white 15%, transparent 16%),
    black;
background-position: 0 0, 80px 80px;

-webkit-background-size:160px 160px;
-moz-background-size:160px 160px;
background-size:160px 160px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's something I was looking for.